# Lightweight PDF reader that supports highlight (Windows)?

Tags: windows, pdf

Foxit is too large, Sumatra is very good and fast, but it can't highlight. I want a PDF reader as fast as Sumatra, but also supports highlight.

Comment: By "too large" you mean MB's on your hard drive? Why is this important for you? Is there some limit?

Comment: Do you need the text to remain highlighted if you close and then reopen the document? Do you need to be able to highlight more than one section of text simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

I use and recommend PDF-XChange Editor from Tracker Software. The free version allows you to highlight the text. Using the keyboard shortcut ctrl+h you can quickly switch to highlight mode.

[image: PDF-XChange Editor Highligth text]

https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-editor